# How to retrive name of button which is in a array?

Tags: php, mysql

My website queries the localhost database and retrieves the data of a 'menu' and displays them in a table. I set one column for buttons. The buttons are assigned names which are in arrays accordance to the 
'ids' which are unique and from the database.

```
  $username="root";
  $password="";
  $database="login";

  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password);
  $selectdb = mysql_select_db("login",$con);

  // get results from database
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, price, category FROM menu")
  or die(mysql_error());

  echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
  echo "<p>Select: <a href=admin_menu.php>Add</a> | <b>Edit</b> | <a href=admin_menu_delete.php>Delete</a> |</p>";
  echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='10'>";
  echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Price ($)</th> <th>Category</th> <th>Edit</th> </tr>";

  // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    if ($row['category'] == '1') {
      $category = "Breakfast";
    }
    if ($row['category'] == '2') {
      $category = "Drinks";
    }
    if ($row['category'] == '3') {
      $category = "Snacks";
    }
    if ($row['category'] == '4') {
      $category = "Main";
    }
    echo "<tr>";     // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['price'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $category . '</td>';
    echo '<td><button type="submit" value="Edit" name="id['.$row['id'].']" /></button>' . '</td>';
    echo "</tr>";
  }

    // close table>
    echo "</table>";
    echo '</form>';
    print_r($_POST);
```

When I click on the button in the 30th row, this is what I see.[image: $post]

So, how do u extract the number 30 in another php page, when I click on the button in the 30th row?

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: if you can`print_r($_POST);` then you can `$_POST['id']`. well, this retrieve all of `id`s in the submitted form, then you need to loop them or just access them using indexes. for starter, just `print_r($_POST['id'])`, hope you get the gists.

Comment: Haha I just realised I've been attempting to call the value in a stupid way. Thanks for the heads up. All i had to do was call it via $POST and add:    if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
      $ids = implode(array_keys($_POST['id']));
      echo "$ids";

Answer (score 0):

You might change your code a little bit like,

```
$username="root";
  $password="";
  $database="login";

  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", $username, $password);
  $selectdb = mysqli_select_db("login",$con);

  // get results from database
  $result = mysqli_query("SELECT id, name, price, category FROM menu")
  or die(mysql_error());

  echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
  echo "<p>Select: <a href=admin_menu.php>Add</a> | <b>Edit</b> | <a href=admin_menu_delete.php>Delete</a> |</p>";
  echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='10'>";
  echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Price ($)</th> <th>Category</th> <th>Edit</th> </tr>";

  // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
    if ($row['category'] == '1') {
      $category = "Breakfast";
    }
    if ($row['category'] == '2') {
      $category = "Drinks";
    }
    if ($row['category'] == '3') {
      $category = "Snacks";
    }
    if ($row['category'] == '4') {
      $category = "Main";
    }
    echo "<tr>";     // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['price'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $category . '</td>';
    echo '<td><button type="submit" value="'.$row['id'].'" name="Edit" />Edit</button>' . '</td>';
    echo "</tr>";
  }

    // close table>
    echo "</table>";
    echo '</form>';
    print_r($_POST);
```

And then,
Access the button value using `$_POST['Edit']`.